# Using Codeigniter-code inside jQuery selector

Tags: jquery, codeigniter

```
<?php foreach($platforms as $platform): ?>
    <input type='button' value='Select' class="button" id="button_<?php echo $platform->id ?>" />
<?php endforeach; ?>


<script>
    $("#button_<?php echo $platform->id ?>").click(function(){
        alert('something');
    });
</script>
```

I do not get my example to work. Is there a way to embed codeigniter code inside jQuery selector? If so how?

Comment: What's your console say?

Comment: U are missing the semicolumns in your php code. It might cause your script to fail.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

To use `$platform->id` you need to move it into a foreach like this:

```
<?php foreach($platforms as $platform): ?>
    <input type='button' value='Select' class="button" id="button_<?php echo $platform->id;?>" />


    <script>
        $("#button_<?php echo $platform->id ?>").click(function(){
            alert('something');
        });
    </script> 
<?php endforeach; ?>
```

because `$platform` is declarated in foreach only, but you are trying to access it outside.